# How can I write the Karatsuba algorithm formally?

Tags: algorithms

I am writing a math paper on the Karatsuba Algorithm. The algorithm is never formally given. What I have so far is

The Karatsuba Algorithm reduces the multiplication of two n-digit numbers to at most single digit multiplication. In general when n is a power of 2.

u=p*r
v=(q-p)*(s-r)
w=q*s. so

a*b=u*10^n+(u+w-v)*10^(n/2)+w

I've never seen an algorithm written formally, i tried looking some up to help me write it formally but couldn't find any. Any feedback would help.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm

Comment: I am pretty sure that the algorithm is very well spelled out with all intricacies by Knuth, probably in Seminumerical Algorithms